# Get Session on models

Tags: session, zend-framework2, session-variables

I read and implement the @Andy0708 answer in this question [Zend Framework 2 passing variable to models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732201/zend-framework-2-passing-variable-to-models/15733364#15733364). 
When I run the example, `$service` is not instanceof `\User\Model\LanguageAwareInterface`, then never set de Language and does't work for me. I can create an instance of `MyModel` class but it's empty because never set nothing.
I don't know if I missing something or if the answer is missing some information.

My reputation it's low than I need to comment an answer. That's why I create this Question.

Comment: Do you get your model from ServiceManager/ServiceLocator?

Comment: thats's quite a simple example and should work as it is, can you post your code example please

Comment: Hi, it's been a while. I'm Sorry. I solved it with this [http://www.jprumeau.com/?p=820](http://www.jprumeau.com/?p=820) (it's in spanish). I missing the factory to create the model object. I hope it helps.